# How to output a file from line x to another

Tags: cat

How can I output the `projects.txt` contents to another file named `newProjects.txt` starting from line 4 for example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do something like `tail -n +5 projects.txt >> newProjects.txt`. The `-n +5` will "skip" the first 4 lines of `projects.txt`.